# Compare Value's of 2 different functions for alert

Tags: javascript, function

Im just a beginner learning Javascript, and i have a problem.

I want to compare value's of 2 different functions. When value "kliks" is higher than value "clicks" , then alert: (...) I know what the problem is, but i dont know how to fix it.

My function code is the following:

```
var kliks = 0;
var clicks = 0;


function clickMe() {
    kliks++;
    document.getElementById("kliks").innerHTML = kliks;

}

function onClick() {
    clicks++;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    return clicks;
}

if (kliks > clicks) {
    alert("Something")
}
```

Because the value's are in the function, the var always give 0 in the IF statement.

I tried to get both functions in 1 function, i tried to post the if statement in the functions, but i dont know how to fix it.

Hope you guys can help me!

Sorry for my horrible english btw ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as follows:

```
var kliks = 0;
var clicks = 0;


function clickMe() {
    kliks++;
    document.getElementById("kliks").innerHTML = kliks;
    check();
}

function onClick() {
    clicks++;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    check();
}

function check() {
  if (kliks > clicks) {
    alert("Something")
  }
}
```

Basically, you need to check, after each click, if `klicks` is greater than `clicks`. This is done by calling the function `check()` in each of `clickMe` and `onClick` functions.

Comment: Thank you soo much! Youre a live saver ;p

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encapsulate your condition checking in a function and call that function in each of your other functions:

```js
var kliks = 0;
var clicks = 0;

function onKlik() {
  kliks++;
  document.getElementById("kliks").innerHTML = kliks;
  checkClicks();
}

function onClick() {
  clicks++;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  checkClicks();
}

function checkClicks() {
  if (kliks > clicks) {
      alert("Something");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="kliks" onclick="onKlik();">kliks</div>
<div id="clicks" onclick="onClick();">clicks</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var kliks = 0;
var clicks = 0;

function clickMe() {
    kliks++;
  document.getElementById("kliks").innerHTML = kliks;
 compare(kliks,clicks);
}

function onClick() {
    clicks++;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    compare(kliks,clicks);
}
var compare = function(kliks,clicks){
 if(kliks > clicks){
alert('something')
}
}
```

```html
<div id="kliks" onclick="clickMe();">kliks</div>
<div id="clicks" onclick="onClick();">clicks</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for youre answer!